# How can I aggregate a multi-level index in Pandas by week, with Day of Week as columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe representing stock price close data that has 2 indices: Date and Day of Week (where 0,1,2,3,4 = Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday). It looks like this:

```
Date          Day     Close

2019-04-08    0       283.01
2019-04-09    1       281.56
2019-04-10    2       282.52
2019-04-11    3       282.44
2019-04-12    4       284.35
...
2020-04-02    3       251.83
2020-04-03    4       248.19
2020-04-06    0       262.35
```

I'd like to convert this into the following:

```
Week Of        0       1       2       3       4

2019-04-08     283.01  281.56  282.52  282.44  284.35
...
2020-03-30     ..      257.75  246.15  251.83  248.19
2020-04-06     262.35  N/A     N/A     N/A     N/A
```

I thought the best way to do this might be through pandas pivot table functionality, but I'm running into issues with its `aggfunc`.

Comment: you can do do crosstab `pd.crosstab(df['Date'],df['Week'],df['Close'],aggfunc='first')` or `pd.crosstab(df['Date'],df['Week'],df['Close'],aggfunc=lambda x : x )`

Comment: @Datanovice, that is very close! Returns this:
    Day              0       1       2       3       4
    row_0                                             
    2019-04-08  283.01     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    2019-04-09     NaN  281.56     NaN     NaN     NaN
    2019-04-10     NaN     NaN  282.52     NaN     NaN
    2019-04-11     NaN     NaN     NaN  282.44     NaN
    2019-04-12     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  284.35
    ...            ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
I will edit my question to clarify some other points

Comment: you can flatten the index by calling `reset_index` or `drop_level` if you have a multi index

Comment: I don't think I need to drop an index, moreso that I need every 5th entry that defines the start date for that week. Wouldn't be the same as "flattening" as it is defined here, but still going to try crosstab!

Comment: @Datanovice, sorry I get what you were trying to tell me now; I should have turned the indices into columns!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `to_period` to extract week and `weekday` to get the weekdays, then `pivot`:

```
# convert to datetime type if not already is
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# extract the new index and columns
df['Day'] = df['Date'].dt.weekday
df['Week'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('W')

result = df.pivot(index='Week', columns='Day', values='Close')
```

Output:

```
Day                         0       1       2       3       4
Week                                                         
2019-04-08/2019-04-14  283.01  281.56  282.52  282.44  284.35
2020-03-30/2020-04-05     NaN     NaN     NaN  251.83  248.19
2020-04-06/2020-04-12  262.35     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Or if you only want Mondays as the `Week`. you can just subtract the `Day` from the `Date`:

```
df['Day'] = df['Date'].dt.weekday
df['Week'] = df['Date'] - pd.to_timedelta(df['Day'], unit='D')

result = df.pivot(index='Week', columns='Day', values='Close')
```

Output:

```
Day              0       1       2       3       4
Week                                              
2019-04-08  283.01  281.56  282.52  282.44  284.35
2020-03-30     NaN     NaN     NaN  251.83  248.19
2020-04-06  262.35     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: This is it !! Thanks so much